# Arithmetic for values inside a maybe, inside a record or How to write the instance for (Num (Maybe a))

Tags: haskell

Given I have the following:

```
data Tick = Tick { _price :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord)

type High = Maybe Tick
type Low = Maybe Tick

data Candle = Candle
  { _open :: Open
  , _high :: High
  , _low :: Low
  , _close :: Close
  } deriving (Eq, Ord)

makeLenses ''Candle
```

When I create a Candle:

```
candle = ...
```

Then I wish to use the calculate the difference between high and low:

```
 axis = high - low
```

Results in:

```
• No instance for (Num High) arising from a use of ‘-’
• In the expression: high - low
  In an equation for ‘axis’: axis = high - low
```

I have tried creating an instance like this:

```
instance Num High where
    (-) (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a - b)
```

But that results in the error:

```
• Illegal instance declaration for ‘Num High’
    (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
     where T is not a synonym.
     Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
• In the instance declaration for ‘Num High’
```

So my question is, what should the instance for `(Num High)` look like to allow my calculation?

Comment: The key point is in the error message: "where T is not a synonym," and the solution is there too "Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this." Of course the way your instance is defined, you'll also have to define `instance Num Tick`

Comment: Thanks @AdamSmith defining `instance Num Tick` and pattern matching the `Just` is enough to get me past this error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arghhhh... no! Don't do that! Why do you think this is a good idea?

`High` is not a number type, because it also contains the non-number value `Nothing`<sup>☆</sup>. (Even any such reasoning aside, it's basically never a good idea to define an instance for a type and class that are both in an established standard library, most certainly not `base`. Such an instance will surprise everybody who knows these libraries and suddenly runs into unexpected instances! Also, if the instance did make sense, the GHC people would probably have already defined it.)

What the `Maybe` does is, it forces you to think about the case where there *is* no number, i.e. where either upper or lower boundary aren't given. I don't know what behaviour you want for this case, but plausible would be to immediately make the `axis`-result `Nothing` too then. This is readily accomplished using `Maybe`'s `Applicative` instance:

```
axis :: Maybe Int
axis = (-) <$> candle^.high <*> candle^.low
```

...provided that `Tick` itself has a `Num` instance, which might not be very prudent either<sup>†</sup> but at least plausible. If it doesn't have a `Num` instance, you need to unwrap the `Tick` constructor:

```
axis = Tick <$> ((-) <$> (_price <$> candle^.high) <*> (_price <$> candle^.low)
```

---

That said, if you insist to define that instance (as you shouldn't), then it's easy enough to do. For one thing, you could just unravel the type synonym:

```
instance Num (Maybe Tick) where
  Just (Tick a) - Just (Tick b) = Just . Tick $ a - b
  _ - _ = Nothing
```

But that's not even necessary; as the compiler already hinted you *can* directly give instances via type synonyms, it's just not Haskell98. Just enable the extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

and then

```
instance Num High where
  ...
```

is accepted, for better or for worse.

---

<sup>☆</sup>
Note that just using `Applicative` for defining a `Num` instance leads to trouble: you want `-` and `+` to be cancellative, i.e. `(a - b) + b ≡ a`. But with the straightforward `a+b = (+)<$>a<*>b` (which can also be written `(+)=liftA2(+)`) you would have

```
(Just 1 - Nothing) + Nothing = Nothing
                             ‡ Just 1
```

...mind, much the same behaviour is already exhibited by the floating-point instances

```
Prelude> (1 - 1/0) + 1/0
NaN
```

but at least there it's understood that infinities and NaN are corner cases where everything gets a bit weird, whereas for a `Maybe Int` you'd expect the `Nothing` to be a pretty normal, “it's just not here” value.

<sup>†</sup>
A better instance is probably

```
import Data.AdditiveGroup
instance AdditiveGroup Tick
```

...which works without any explicit implementation, provided you add `Generic` to the data definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics
data Tick = Tick { _price :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

With that defined, you can then do

```
axis = (^-^) <$> candle^.high <*> candle^.low
```

Comment: I think it would be great if you actually explain why having `instance Num a => Num (Maybe a)` is wrong, rather than being emotional and referring to a supposed authority. *(There are many things in Prelude that are widely considered wrong, such as `foldl` and `head`.)* I believe you in that experience may show it's not as great as it looks, but it does look plausible to be able to say just `a - b` rather than `(-) <$> a <*> b`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really mean “the standard is perfect” (though one thing I'd attest is that if it's at all sensible to define an instance, they _will_ generally have written it already... in fact IMO they've defined rather _too many_ instances, such as `Foldable (a,)`). I mostly meant that it's generally not a good idea to add orphan instances to a library, unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Maybe I should point out this is my first Haskell project, and I'm only a few weeks in. I appreciate the lesson though, I'll try to unpick and understand your answer so I can correct my mistake.